# I GET 404 ERROR IN AXON SAGA IMPLEMENTATION WHEN I SEND POST REQUEST.WHAT MIGHT BE THE REASON?

Tags: java, spring-boot, event-handling, axon, saga

i implemented SAGA using Axon and Spring Boot.It is simple order and customer service.Everything looks fine,however when i send post request via postman ,i got 404 NOT FOUND.I guess the problem is related to OrderManagementSaga.java Please help me!

OrderManagementSaga.java

```
@Saga
public class OrderManagementSaga {

    @Inject
    private transient CommandGateway commandGateway;

    @StartSaga
    @SagaEventHandler(associationProperty = "orderId")
    public void handle(OrderCreatedEvent orderCreatedEvent){

        
       SagaLifecycle.associateWith("customerId", orderCreatedEvent.customerId);

        
            commandGateway.send(new CreateInvoiceCommand(orderCreatedEvent.customerId,orderCreatedEvent.price,orderCreatedEvent.orderId));
     

       
    }

    @SagaEventHandler(associationProperty = "customerId")
    public void handle(InvoiceCreatedEvent invoiceCreatedEvent){
      
        
        SagaLifecycle.associateWith("orderId",invoiceCreatedEvent.orderId);
        
        commandGateway.send(new UpdateOrderStatusCommand(invoiceCreatedEvent.orderId, invoiceCreatedEvent.price, invoiceCreatedEvent.customerId));
       
        
        
    }


    @SagaEventHandler(associationProperty = "orderId")
    public void handle(OrderUpdatedEvent orderUpdatedEvent){
        SagaLifecycle.end();
    }
}
```

OrderCommandController.java

```
@RestController
public class OrderCommandController {
    
    private OrderCommandService orderCommandService;

    public OrderCommandController(OrderCommandService orderCommandService) {
        this.orderCommandService = orderCommandService;
    }

    @PostMapping("/orders")
    public CompletableFuture<String> createOrder(@RequestBody OrderCreateDTO orderCreateDTO){
        return orderCommandService.createOrder(orderCreateDTO);
    }
    

}
```

OrderAggregate.java

```
@Aggregate
public class OrderAggregate {
    

    

    @AggregateIdentifier
    private String orderId;
    
    private BigDecimal price;
    
    private OrderStatus orderStatus;
    
    private String customerId;

    public OrderAggregate() {
    }

    @CommandHandler
    public OrderAggregate(CreateOrderCommand createOrderCommand) {
        AggregateLifecycle.apply(new OrderCreatedEvent(createOrderCommand.orderId,createOrderCommand.price, createOrderCommand.customerId));
    }

    @EventSourcingHandler
    protected void on(OrderCreatedEvent orderCreatedEvent) {
        this.orderId = orderCreatedEvent.orderId;
        this.customerId = orderCreatedEvent.customerId;
        this.orderStatus = OrderStatus.CREATED;
    }

    @CommandHandler
    protected void on(UpdateOrderStatusCommand updateOrderStatusCommand) {
        AggregateLifecycle
                .apply(new OrderUpdatedEvent(updateOrderStatusCommand.orderId,updateOrderStatusCommand.customerıd,updateOrderStatusCommand.price,OrderStatus.CREATED));
    }

    @EventSourcingHandler
    protected void on(OrderUpdatedEvent orderUpdatedEvent) {
        this.customerId = orderUpdatedEvent.customerId;
        this.orderId = orderUpdatedEvent.orderId;
        this.orderStatus = OrderStatus.APPROVED;
        this.price = orderUpdatedEvent.price;
    }
```

CustomerAggregate.java

```
@Aggregate
public class CustomerAggregate {

    @AggregateIdentifier
    private String customerId;
    
    private BigDecimal budget;
    
    private String orderId;
 


    


    public CustomerAggregate(String customerId, BigDecimal budget, String orderId) {
        super();
        this.customerId = customerId;
        this.budget = budget;
        this.orderId = orderId;
    }
    @CommandHandler
    public CustomerAggregate(CreateInvoiceCommand createInvoiceCommand){
        
        AggregateLifecycle.apply(new InvoiceCreatedEvent(createInvoiceCommand.price, createInvoiceCommand.customerId, createInvoiceCommand.orderId));
    

    }
    @EventSourcingHandler
    protected void on(InvoiceCreatedEvent invoiceCreatedEvent){
        
        this.customerId = invoiceCreatedEvent.customerId;
        this.budget = this.budget.subtract(invoiceCreatedEvent.price);
        this.orderId = invoiceCreatedEvent.orderId;
        
    }

    

    public String getCustomerId() {
        return customerId;
    }
    public void setCustomerId(String customerId) {
        this.customerId = customerId;
    }
    public BigDecimal getBudget() {
        return budget;
    }

    public void setBudget(BigDecimal budget) {
        this.budget = budget;
    }
    
    
}
```

I don't think the problem is related with command and event classes ,so i only share one of them as example;
CreateOrderCommand.java

```
public class CreateOrderCommand {
    
     @TargetAggregateIdentifier
        public final String orderId;
        public final String customerId;
        public final BigDecimal price;
        public CreateOrderCommand(String orderId, String customerId, BigDecimal price) {
            super();
            this.orderId = orderId;
            this.customerId = customerId;
            this.price = price;
            
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

404 indicates that you can not reach the REST controller in the first place. Can this be debugged and checked? If this is working as expected, then the implementation of this controller could be examined in more detail: what is `orderCommandService` that is injected in the REST controller. Hopefully, it is using the Axon command gateway to send the command to `OrderAggregate`. The `OrderAggregate` will publish an event of type `OrderCreatedEvent` which should start the Saga.

Comment: Please note that `orderCommandService` has to be declared as Spring Bean in order to be injected into the REST controller